# My lost host server is running in cmd but in browser it is showing localhost didn't send any data

Tags: node.js, express, networking, localhost, node-modules

[hyper terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8TjT.png)

[my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th9rz.png)
code is :

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use("/",(request ,res)=> res.end("Hello World"));
app.listen(port , ()=>{
    console.log("server is at 3000");
});
```

Comment: res.send, not res.end.

Comment: The docs for the end method suggest using something else if you are sending data, but it should still work: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end. What do you see if you curl that endpoint?

Comment: I think the code above it's working fine. Make sure you get the url: `localhost:3000/` and you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss typed `res.send`

```js
app.use("/", (request ,res) => res.send("Hello World"));
```

Comment: it is  not making any difference

Comment: How do you send request to server? 

Open browser and type http://localhost:3000/ in address bar. You should see hello world from server.

Comment: And are you sure you are running correct app? Output in attached screenshot with server logs should be `server is at 3000`

Comment: Ya its the same code,  i just made this change before posting, remaining is exactly same